# Store multiple values in a single cell instead of in different rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way I can store multiple values in a single cell instead of different rows, and search for them?

**Can I do:**

```
pId | available
1   | US,UK,CA,SE
2   | US,SE
```

**Instead of:**

```
pId | available
1   | US
1   | UK
1   | CA
1   | SE
```

**Then do:**

```
select pId from table where available = 'US'
```

Comment: How would you ensure that you only assign one code once in the first version?

Comment: The SQL tag refers to the standard language, not for questions about vendor extensions (e.g. MySQL, MS SQL Server), so if you think your question relates to a specific extension, use that extension's tag instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* do that, but it makes the query inefficient. You can look for a substring in the field, but that means that the query can't make use of any index, which is a big performance issue when you have many rows in your table.

This is how you would use it in your special case with two character codes:

```
select pId from table where find_in_set('US', available)
```

Keeping the values in separate records makes every operation where you use the values, like filtering and joining, more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the like operator to get the result

```
Select pid from table where available like '%US%'
```